# Auto close notice:

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

In   some...controller.rb  i have string

```
redirect_to posts_path, notice: 'Login or register'
```

In some...views.html.erb

```
  <% if notice.present? %>
 <div class="alert alert-info fade in">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
    <strong><%= notice %></strong> 
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In  application.js i add

```
$(".alert-info" ).fadeOut(3000);
$(".alert" ).fadeOut(3000);
$(".alert-success" ).fadeOut(3000);
$(".alert-danger" ).fadeOut(3000);
```

but alert , do not want to close itself

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Do you want your notice will disappear after some times?

Comment: Yes i want   that notice  disappear after some time. (for example
 5 second)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using `jquery`. You have to call `$('.alert').delay(5000).fadeOut();` with in jquery `$(document).ready` method that ensure script executed after DOM loading.

First be sure that you add your `application.js` to your layout page.

Add following code

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.alert').delay(5000).fadeOut();
  });
```

[demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epPZQp)

Comment: Thanks it's working fine. But in one moment it's not work. :( After logout.


'
  def logout
    reset_session
    redirect_to root_path
    flash[:notice]='You successful logout'
  end
'

Comment: first check, do your logout page layout include application.js if not include it. Second inspect your notice( which does not fedout) on browser and check where it is in `<div class="alert alert-info fade in"> ` or not. If not then add ` $('.new-class').delay(5000).fadeOut();` in js file. If it's not solve your problem then copy solution code to root page(where you display notice) and check where it is work or not.